# Stored Procedure Return Types in Visual Studio OR

Tags: stored-procedures, visual-studio-2012

I have a very simple stored procedure running on my SQL Server 2005 database.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Survey_Response_DELETE_For_Survey]
    @surveyId uniqueidentifier
AS
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM SurveyResponse
    WHERE SurveyId = @surveyId

    RETURN 0   -- Ideally this would be RETURN @@ROWCOUNT
END
```

When I drag the store procedure onto the O/R Designer surface (Visual Studio 2012), I get the message:

**The return types for the following stored procedures could not be detected.  Set the return type for each stored procedure in the Properties window**

When I try and do this, I select *'int (System.Int32)'* and get a warning message saying that the change cannot be undone, but the property window doesn't update to show 'int', it simply shows *'(None)'*

I have tried...

- Re-creating the stored procedure
- Deleting and re-creating the database connection in the O/R
- Deleting the connection, exiting Visual Studio, re-creating the connection

None of which work.  Having now spent a day-and-half and would be grateful for any ideas/suggestions.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you are too far in to go back now, but in my experience using the designer is a total nightmare; have you considered using EF code first as most of these problems go away?

Comment: It's an old(ish) project and uses LINQ as the implementation for a Data Driven Domain Model (abstraction of the data from the implementation), so EF is not really a practical option, not at this point anyway, but thanks for the suggestion.